# Build Errors When Attempting to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting build errors when attempting to publish/build my Visual Studio Team Services (previously VS Online) project to Azure from VS2015.  It's the generic Reference could not be found items..

The type or namespace name 'Ninject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I was getting Nuget related errors that called Nuget out specifically prior but I changed a setting to get past that although now I can't recall what that actually was. Was just a True/False setting in one of the config files.

Is there maybe something within the nuget.config that should be standardly configured for anything being published to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "NuGet restore" step in the build definition?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I see it.  Here's everything there...

NuGet restore
Build Solution
Test Assemblies
Publish symbols path
Copy Files
Publish Artifact:drop

Comment: Is ninject referenced in the packages.config file for the project?